# Cannot undertand the mixed outcomes of an .htaccess re-write rule / regex

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a simple website comprised of one page with a div that gets populated with ajax content based on the links the user selects. This site is running on an Apache server with an .htaccess file in the domain's root directory. Requests to www.mydomain.com are directed to scripts/index.php while requests for dynamic content (but not resource files) are directed to the same .php script with the requested content passed as a parameter (e.g., www.mydomain.com/myProject will be rewritten as scripts/index.php?dynContent=myProject).

My rewrite rules are below and for the most part they are performing those described tasks properly; however, I've encountered some URLs that do not match the second condition even though I would expect them to -- though this is the first time I've had to write rules for an .htaccess file so I don't really know what I'm talking about... A good example of a URL that fails the second condition is www.mydomain.com/about, but I've encountered many more just by testing random words/letters.

Can you tell me why www.mydomain.com/about fails the second condition? Also, if there is a more elegant way to achieve the objectives I described above, I would love to learn about it. Thank you!!

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ scripts/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*[^index.php|.css|.js|.jpg|.html|.swf]$
RewriteRule .* scripts/index.php?dynContent=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because regex in your 2nd rules is incorrect.

Change your code to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ scripts/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php|css|js|jpe?g|html|swf)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ scripts/index.php?dynContent=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Anubhava, I tried your solution but didn't have immediate success. I ended up mixing my original solution with yours, which seems to work well.

Comment: Ok can you post your final code in question so that I can verify and suggest accordingly.

Comment: Here it is. I hit the 5-minute comment edit limit...
    
    `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php|css|js|jpe?g|html|swf)$`
    `RewriteRule (.*) scripts/index.php?dynContent=$1 [L]`

Because rule #1 will direct www.mydomain.com to scripts/index.php, I think I must include .php files in your negative match for the condition #2. And I need to pass the URI as a parameter to the script, so I used (.*) in the rule. Do you agree with this tactic or am I looking at it the wrong way?

Comment: Actually based on your comments I edited the answer to add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` condition since to make it more robust. There can be other standard files like `robots.txt, favicon.ico` and difficult to list all of them. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` excludes all existing files from that rewrite.

Comment: So two more questions! I've seen `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` but have not yet developed a good grasp of how exactly `REQUEST_FILENAME` functions. Does it make the file extension match completely redundant? I just tried a test on my site, and `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` seemed to do the job just fine on its own. Second, is there any functional difference between `(.*)` and `^(.*)$`? From what I've seen so far, the latter is more common but I wasn't sure if they performed any differently. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes it is true that `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` check makes other check redundant but only when `fils.js` exists. If for example `file.js` doesn't exist then `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` won't be true for it. As you would have guessed that `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` simply means if request is NOT for a valid file. Also `(.*)` is pretty much same as `^(.*)$` but just as a good practice I prefer using anchors `^ and $` in my regex patterns.